# What does "variance unity" mean?: "A normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance unity".

Tags: probability, variance

I've just come across the sentence:

"Suppose you have the sample $\ldots$ from a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance unity."

What does variance unity mean? Variance equals 1? I can't seem to find clarification of the phrase.

Comment: "Unity" is sometimes a synonym for the number 1.

Comment: Yes, variance equal to 1.

Comment: Often the correct way to say it is "unit variance".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I'm putting this as an answer so that the question does not remain unanswered.)

*Variance unity* means *a variance equal to 1*.

Comment: Thank you. I was unsure if proper procedure was to add the answer myself or allow one of the above commenters to do so.

Comment: I recommend that you wait for someone to give an answer as an actual answer (and not as a comment).  You can address a comment to the one who commented an answer, asking that person to write it as an actual answer.  However, if a few days have gone by and the only answer is in a comment, you can write your own answer.  In this case, you might want to make the answer community wiki so that it doesn't seem you just did it to get the points.

Comment: In retrospect, I guess I should have first asked the commenters to write their answers as actual answers before I wrote mine.